# Upon refresh of the page, I am logged out? Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jwt

I am using Redux with ReactJS. I also am utilizing devise-JWT for auth. Upon a refresh of the page, my state is changed and loggedIn becomes "false". I also get 400 Bad Request error upon posting data through fetch. I can login just fine and be redirected.

My user reducer:

```js
import {
    SIGNUP_USER, 
    LOGIN_USER,
    LOGOUT_USER,
    STORE_TOKEN
} from '../actions/types'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    loggedIn: false,
    currentUser: {}
} 

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case SIGNUP_USER:
            return {
                ...state, 
                loggedIn: true,
                currentUser: action.payload
            }
        case LOGIN_USER:
            return {
                ...state, 
                loggedIn: true,
                currentUser: action.payload
            }
        case LOGOUT_USER:
            return { 
                ...state, 
                user: state.users.filter(user => user.id !== action.payload.id),
                loggedIn: false
            }

        case STORE_TOKEN:
            return {
                token: action.payload.token,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

My action:

```js
export function loginUser(data){
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                user: {
                    ...data
                }
            })
        })
        .then(resp => {
            //debugger
            if (resp.ok) {
                resp.json().then(json => {
                    localStorage.setItem('token', json.token)
                    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER, payload: json })
                })
               
            } 
        })
    }
}
```

My login component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import { loginUser } from '../actions/index'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Login extends React.Component {
    state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }


     handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        let credentials  = this.state
        this.props.loginUser(credentials)
        this.props.history.push('/bookmarks')
        
    }

    
    handleChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
    
   render() {
     const { email, password } = this.state
     return (
         <div className="login-form">
           <h1>Login</h1>
           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
             <div>
               <TextField type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={this.handleChange} value={email} />
             </div>
             <div>
               <TextField type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handleChange} value={password}/>
             </div><br></br>
             <Button type="submit" value="Login">Login</Button>
           </form>
         </div>
     )
   }

} 



const mapDispatch = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loginUser: (credentials) => dispatch(loginUser(credentials))
    
  }
}


export default connect(null, mapDispatch)(Login)
```

I used devise-JWT for authentication.

Answer (score 3):

You're logged out because the only place you store the credentials is in the redux store, which is (essentially) a variable.

When you refresh the page, you reinitialise the store to the default state.

You haven't stored the credentials anywhere where they would persist, such as local storage or a cookie.

Comment: Thank you Quentin! That makes sense.